# libGDX desktop application JAR generation

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I have a libGDX project(which is also desktop compatible) and would like to export its desktop application to a JAR file, to run it like a standalone application. How can I do this with use of Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LibGDX projects are still gradle-based, whatever IDE you are using.

Thus you can use [Gradle on the Commandline](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline) to package your application.

For desktop you do this via `gradlew desktop:dist`. After that the resulting runnable jar file will be in `desktop/build/libs/`.

Comment: Are there any differences between packr and this?

Comment: They are completely different things. Packr bundles your app together with a JVM. That way users don't need to have their JVM installed, and you can make sure they have a JVM, which works with your app.

Comment: How to set `assets` folder location?